# IBOutlet connect in xcode5

Tags: ios, xcode, iboutlet

I'm having an issue making an IBOutlet connection and I'm hoping somebody can help me with this issue.  I have searched all over and seems as though some other people have had this issue as well, but haven't found something that works.  I get Xcode setup the way recommended and holding down control and dragging to the .h file is not giving me anywhere to add the connection. I know I'm not using the column all the way to the left.  Trying to make a connection of the buttons.

Comment: Did you set the class for the ViewController?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ8NS.png

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I'm new at this and still learning a lot.  That worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to set the custom class for the ViewController.